# What is Manasa Puja?

Tags: gods, puja, time

My Questions are:

- What is the meaning of Manasa Puja?
- How to perfom Manasa Puja of a deity ?
- What is right time to do this?

Comment: You can visit the following links-
Manasic puja by Swami Shivananda-
http://sivanandaonline.org/public_html/?cmd=displaysection&section_id=502 Ganesha Manasik Puja-
http://ganeshmanaspuja.blogspot.in/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Manasa Puja* means mental worship of the deity. This is one of the eight forms through which the deity can be worshipped ([SB - 11.27.12](http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/11/27/12) ). This is essepcially done by the *niskama bhaktas* only out of love for the God and without any material desires.

The process and time is basically similar to general outward worship of the deity, but the idol, puja articles etc. are imagined in the mind by the devotee:

> *dravyaiḥ prasiddhair mad-yāgaḥ pratimādiṣv amāyinaḥ
>
>   bhaktasya ca yathā-labdhair hṛdi bhāvena caiva hi* [SB - 11.27.15]
>
> **Meaning**
>   One should worship Me in My Deity forms by offering the most excellent paraphernalia. But a devotee completely freed from material desire may worship Me with whatever he is able to obtain, and may even worship Me within his heart with mental paraphernalia.

And because it is based on the devotees imagination and devotion, he has no limitation regarding how to decorate the deity, what items to use for worship, what process to follow and so on. This is generally the primary mode of worship for those who follow the *raganuga bhakti* tradition. When devotion and love for the diety becomes stronger there remains no constraint of time for the puja and the devotee does it at any time and even throughout the whole day.